# Cannot connect to the reMarkable web interface anymore

Tags: user-interface, timeout, usb, tablet, e-ink

usually I can connect via a USB cable from my MacBook to my reMarkable tablet. Therefore, I have to enter http://10.11.99.1 in a web browser. I was using this type of connection for a long time but after re-installing my Mac from scratch I cannot connect to the reMarkable anymore, the connection breaks with a timeout. Any ideas on how to proceed?